# EXE file for python scripts

Tags: windows, python-2.7, py2exe

i am using python 2.7 and py2exe to try and make an exe file for my script. but it is not going so well.. my file works perfectly until I add the py2exe commands what am I doin wrong here? I need to know how to write the setup function and call it so that python knows to create and EXE file not just a compiled .py. Also this is attempted using a windows operating system.

```
from time import strftime
import os.path
# setup.py
import py2exe

setup(console=["LogFile.py"])


def main():
    getTime()

def getTime():
    time = strftime("%Y-%m-%d %I:%M:%S")
    printTime(time)

def printTime(time):
    savePath = "C:\Users\Nicholas\Documents"
    logFile = "LogInLog.txt"
    files = open(os.path.join(savePath, logFile), "a+")
    openPosition = files.tell()
    files.write("A LogIn occured.")
    files.write(time)
    files.seek(openPosition)
    print(files.read())
    files.close()



main()
```

Comment: I have created a setup file for this program but I can not get past the py2exe command to execute I keep getting an invalid syntax error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't work that way

First, remove the `setup` line from your script. The setup script is a different script. Your script, fixed:

```
from time import strftime
import os.path

def main():
    getTime()

def getTime():
    time = strftime("%Y-%m-%d %I:%M:%S")
    printTime(time)

def printTime(time):
    savePath = r"C:\Users\Nicholas\Documents"
    logFile = "LogInLog.txt"
    files = open(os.path.join(savePath, logFile), "a+")
    openPosition = files.tell()
    files.write("A LogIn occured.")
    files.write(time)
    files.seek(openPosition)
    print(files.read())
    files.close()
```

Then create a file called `setup.py`

```
import py2exe
from distutils.core import setup
setup(console=["LogFile.py"])
```

Then type (in a command prompt, ***not from within python interpreter***):

```
python setup.py py2exe
```

it creates the executable & aux files in `dist` subdir

After that go to `dist`

```
C:\DATA\jff\data\python\stackoverflow\dist>LogFile.exe
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "LogFile.py", line 25, in <module>
  File "LogFile.py", line 6, in main
  File "LogFile.py", line 10, in getTime
  File "LogFile.py", line 15, in printTime
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\Nicholas\\Documents\\LogInLog.txt'
```

crashing, normal I don't have your directories: it works!!

Comment: where am I typing Then type:
python setup.py py2exe

Comment: Where am I supposed to be typing and running the setup.py file? it is not working for me I keep receiving symtax error : invalid syntax

Comment: this is what I get back from using the command C:\python27\setup.py\py2exe
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is 4AC8-FD98

 Directory of C:\python27\setup.py

File Not Found

C:\Users\Nicholas>dir C:\python27\setup.py
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is 4AC8-FD98

 Directory of C:\python27

08/21/2016  04:31 PM                88 setup.py
               1 File(s)             88 bytes
               0 Dir(s)  385,825,923,072 bytes free

C:\Users\Nicholas>

Comment: Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.10586]
(c) 2015 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\Nicholas>dir C:\python27\setup.py\py2exe
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is 4AC8-FD98

 Directory of C:\python27\setup.py

File Not Found

C:\Users\Nicholas>

Comment: something is reaaaally wrong on your setup. You seem to have a directory called `setup.py` in your python installation! Delete it. Work in another directory. I'm sorry, you won't have much more info with the tutorial posted in the above (fine) answer.

Comment: When I run the setup file should there be anything else within the file other than 
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe

setup(console=["LogFile.py"])

Comment: I did what u suggested and :\Users\Nicholas>dir C:\users\Nicholas\setup.py
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is 4AC8-FD98

 Directory of C:\users\Nicholas

08/21/2016  04:31 PM                88 setup.py
               1 File(s)             88 bytes
               0 Dir(s)  385,824,022,528 bytes free

C:\Users\Nicholas>

Comment: Did I say to use `dir` ? I don't think so!

Comment: C:\Users\Nicholas>C:\users\nicholas\setup.py
usage: setup.py [global_opts] cmd1 [cmd1_opts] [cmd2 [cmd2_opts] ...]
   or: setup.py --help [cmd1 cmd2 ...]
   or: setup.py --help-commands
   or: setup.py cmd --help

error: no commands supplied

Comment: You're doing this on purpose or what? in my answer: `python setup.py py2exe`

Comment: no it really just was not working but I just got it... I was going as a directory all the way through not writing the py2exe as a command after python27\setup.py

Comment: it's not very natural, I usually wrap it in some other command because I never remember it, but there must be a deep reason. Glad that it works. Hardest 15 rep points ever :)

Answer (score 1):

Look at this [py2exe Tutorial](http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/Tutorial).

Your mistakes are:
    1. Missed `from distutils.core import setup`
    2. Did not make a new file to use py2exe.

You need:
    1. Remove `import py2exe`and `setup(console=["LogFile.py"])`
    2. create new file "psetup.py", with code bellow:

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe
setup(console=["your_code_name.py"])
```

Comment: I have read the tutorial for py2exe it doesn't make sense to me. I've tried what they say to do on there and it doesn't seem to work. But I can see that's because I was typing within my pyscript. I have the setup file created but now what do I do? I type python setup.py py2exe but where how do I get the setup script to run and make my exe file

Comment: That is a different tutorial then I have read previously helps me very much thank you :)